Gamebook about elf girl with white hair
The book could be written in the early 2000s, maybe. This elf girl had white or pale purple hair and a vest. The book itself was really nicely illustrated; I remember this double page with a town square in some fantasy town, in the middle of pages was this big tree with some hidden objects (I think).
There was a elf workshop, I don't remember what it was for, but there was this adult elf and younger disciple who broke a vase or something. Also there was some winter pages with snow beast and snow queen.
You could find some crystals throughout the book. On one page there was big woman's face in stone from the side. She had hair tied in side-bun or something and it was some labyrinth or mechanism.

Was this in colour throughout, or just the cover? Was it regular book size, or large size?

It was fully in color, hardback, larger and wider book than reguler formats.
